# Facebook graph api explorer doesn't show 'Friends Data Permission' tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Trying to use Facebook Graph API Explorer.

when selecting 'Get Access Token' its only showing two tabs: 'User Data Permissions' and 'Extended Permissions'. its missing 'Friends Data Permissions'.

Does anyone have any idea why?

couldn't attach a photo as i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the `friends_*` permissions were removed in v2.0

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to user v1.0 in a new application? Or are you locked to use a newer version of the API?

Comment: They are locked at a newer version